How do I dynamically reference my hashtable?
I am creating a standards specific ADUC replacement form, I have most of it done I just have to finished up validation. I call my function...utilize $this class...but I'm not sure how to reference the rest of my hashtable by going "up" in my hashtable path. I have never had to do this before.
$formField.IPPhone.Field.Add_TextChanged({
            TestPhoneNumberValid
        })

I call my validation function, goal would be to keep this code as simple as this, I will use TestPhoneNumberValid with my other "Phone" fields.
function TestPhoneNumberValid  {
        if ($this.MaskCompleted -eq $true -or ($this.Text -replace '\s','').Length -eq 3 ) {
            
        ###The following commands are what I want to do but what I need help referencing dynamically based on $this
            $formField.IPPhone.Validated = $true
            $formField.IPPhone.Info.Text = ""
        } Else {
            $formField.IPPhone.Info.Text = "Phone number is not in a valid format of (555) 555-5555"
        }
}


The shortest answer would be "You don't" (objects don't have any reference to their container, since they can be in more than one container), but from the small snippet it's not clear what the best approach would be (maybe passing the entire dict as a closure, if PowerShell even has those, or something along the lines?), so I'd say maybe take this to Code Review SE, or to StackOverflow, since at this point it's really a programming question and not a "shell script" question.

Read up some here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.4 and see if this gives you any ideas how to go about attempting what you are doing. This is also based on the small snippet and other context provided. Look over this section too as it may be of importance https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.4#inheritance-limitations

What is $formField? What is $formField.IPPhone? Show us how you create the hashtable :)

@MathiasR.Jessen $formField is the main hashtable that stores all the form elements. It's not really important here. What outlined so far is everything that is needed to illustrate what I am trying to do.

So $formField.IPPhone is also a hashtable?

A simple solution is to flip the relationship around - use PowerShell's extended type system to attach the hashtable containing metadata to the form control:
$phoneField = [System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox]::new(...)
# ... configure the form control as you would normally here

# then attach the hashtable
$phoneField |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name _metadata -Value @{Validated=$false;Info=@{Text=''}}

In the event handler, reference the automatic variable $Sender to get the form control that raised the event:
$phoneField.add_TextChanged({
  # instead of $this, use $sender - the form control that raised the event
  TestPhoneNumberValid $sender
})

Now you can reference the attached metadata inside the validation function:
function TestPhoneNumberValid {
  param($field)

  if ($field.MaskCompleted -or ($field.Text -replace '\s').Length -eq 3) {
    $field._metadata.Validated = $true
    $field._metadata.Info.Text = ''
  }
  else {
    $field._metadata.Validated = $false
    $field._metadata.Info.Text = 'Phone number is not in a valid format of (555) 555-5555'
  }
}

